# How can I change the content based on the current slide data index with swiper.js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to **Swiper** here is one of the best framework sliders I've ever used, currently, I want to create a relationship between 2 div tags, 1 tag is the content of each slide, 1 tag is the function of the slides when the slide active will show the content of that slide, how can I do that?

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  effect: "coverflow",
  grabCursor: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
  slidesPerView: "auto",
  coverflowEffect: {
    rotate: 20,
    stretch: 0,
    depth: 350,
    modifier: 1,
    slideShadows: true
  },
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination"
  }
});
```

```css
.items_content-2, .items_content-3 {
 display : none;
}
.picture img {
  width : 100%;
  height : 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.1/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="content">
 <div class="items_content-1">
  Slide-1
 </div>
 <div class="items_content-2">
  Slide-2
 </div>
 <div class="items_content-3">
  Slide-3
 </div>
</div>
<div class="swiper-container">
 <div class="swiper-wrapper">
  <div class="swiper-slide">
   <div class="picture one">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?sig=52" alt="">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">
   <div class="picture">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?sig=24" alt="">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">
   <div class="picture">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?sig=53" alt="">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I have updated my code, can you see and help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two swipers:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  effect: "coverflow",
  grabCursor: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
  slidesPerView: "auto",
  coverflowEffect: {
    rotate: 20,
    stretch: 0,
    depth: 350,
    modifier: 1,
    slideShadows: true
  },
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination"
  }
});

   var swiper2 = new Swiper(".swiper-container2", {
  effect: "coverflow",
  grabCursor: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
  slidesPerView: "auto",
  coverflowEffect: {
    rotate: 20,
    stretch: 0,
    depth: 350,
    modifier: 1,
    slideShadows: true
  },
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination"
  }
});
swiper2.params.control = swiper;
swiper.params.control = swiper2;
```

```css
.picture img {
  width : 100%;
  height : 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.1/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- first swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container2">
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="items_content-1">
            Slide-1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="items_content-2">
            Slide-2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="items_content-3">
            Slide-3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- second swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container">
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="picture one">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?sig=52" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="picture">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?sig=24" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="picture">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?sig=53" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my problem is that I want to separate 2 parts and when the slide is sliding, the content will be displayed in another part.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have used this method already, and I feel this is not necessary, according to what I learn, can use the callback to call the swiper onChange event event but my problem I don't know how to use it to create what I want.